# export render php 5.1 with some library similar to dompdf

Tags: php, pdf

I was currently doing it with DOMPDF, with php 5.3, but migrate to a php 5.1 and DOMPDF is not compatible with that php version.

I need to know if there is any other library that allows me to export my .php in a simple way as it did with DOMPDF without writing each fragment as it is with fpdf :(

Comment: I *really* hope you mean you're migrating to PHP **7.1** and not **5.1**. If so, check the version of DOMPDF you're using, the latest version should be compatible with PHP 7.

Comment: @rickdenhaan  migrate to php 5.1

Comment: I **strongly** recommend against that. PHP 5.1 has been abandoned [since 2006](http://php.net/eol.php). Having said that, you could try an older version of DOMPDF. Version 0.7.0 introduced a minimum requirement for PHP 5.3, but 0.6.2 and earlier worked on PHP 5.0 and higher.

Comment: @rickdenhaan 
Previous versions do not work either. Do you know any other library that is as simple as DOMPDF?

Comment: Nothing that will still work on that version of PHP.

Comment: Why are you migrating **to** PHP 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I get it with dompdf version 6.1 by enabling curl module, and parserhtml "true".